# Sampling weather raster by date in GPS dataframe in GEE

Tags: google-earth-engine, gps, remote-sensing, geemap

I am trying to extract the u and v component of the daily ERA-5 wind reanalysis to datapoints from a GPS dataset of mule deer. I am wanting to only extract the wind to points based on the date of the point, which is indicated by a column in the data named **cDate**. The only other column to include is **id_date** which will allow me to re-merge these data with the original GPS set.

Is there a way to iteratively filter an image collection based on contents of the dataset, in this case the date of the lat-long location?

This is the code so far:

````
Map.addLayer(rdh, {}, 'sub');
print(rdh.limit(10), 'sub');

// Call in image collection and filter.
var era5 = ee.ImageCollection("ECMWF/ERA5/DAILY")
    .filterDate('2014-01-01', '2014-12-31')
    .filterBounds(geometry)
    .select(['u_component_of_wind_10m','v_component_of_wind_10m'])
    .map(function(image) {
        return image.clip(geometry);
    });

print(era5, 'era5');
//Map.addLayer(era5, {}, 'era5');

// Convert to a multiband image.
var era5Image = era5.toBands();
print(era5Image, 'era5Image');


// Call the sample regions function.
var samples = era5Image.sampleRegions({
    collection: rdh,
    properties: ['id_date'],
    scale: 27830
});

print(samples.limit(10), 'samples'); ```
````

Comment: As the code is written, I get user error limit bugs

Comment: This very much depends on `rdh`. Please share your complete script (use the `Get Link` button in the code editor), and make sure all used assets are shared.